# How can I control the video height of OMXPlayer?

Tags: raspbian, omxplayer

I installed OMXPlayer which plays well but sometimes the screen size is well beyond the default. Since controls are off screen when this occurs you can only reboot to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

OK, first of all: There is no need to reboot - you can just kill omxplayer's process (`pkill omxplayer` or `kill xxxx`, where xxxx is the PID - sometimes you may have to use `kill -9 xxxx`).
In order to issue the kill command, you can either ssh into your Pi from another box, or just open a terminal and type, in the blind, if the player obscures it, or even hit an ALT-F3 to use another tty (obviously, if you have the patience, you can even just wait for whatever is playing to just finish).

But you have other options - better ones, too:

1) You can use omxplayer's shortcuts to advance the playing to its end, or just plain stop it. From `man omxplayer`: "**q**     exit omxplayer"

2) You can  set the size of the playing window in advance, invoking omxplayer (again from `man omxplayer`) with parameters like --win 'x1 y1 x2 y2'  or --win x1,y1,x2,y2
e.g `omxplayer --win 0,0,500,400 myfile.avi` -   will play myfile.avi in a window starting at top left and a size 500x400

In general, `man` is your ally. Don't hesitate to use it...